# Universal property of the uniform metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(Y,d)$ be a metric space and $X$ be a set. Then the uniform metric on $Y^X$ is defined by
$$ \rho(f,g)=\sup_{x \in X}\big[\min (1,d(f(x),g(x))\big]$$
This has metric has the nice property that $f_n \to f$ in the induced topology iff $f_n \to f$ uniformly, in the traditional sense.

My question is: is this topology characterized by this property? I.e., any other topology on $Y^X$ satisfying the above property must be the one induced by $\rho$?

---

Expanding definitions, we get that the topology on $Y^X$ must satisfy that $f_n \to f$ uniformly iff for any open $U \ni f$, there is some $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $f_n \in U$.

The problem is that it seems that a topology could be finer, provided it does not modify the uniform limits $f_n \to f$, but I haven't been able to show a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that it seems that a topology could be finer,...

This is actually backwards - the problem is that the topology could be coarser.  Every closed set in any topology is closed under convergent sequences, so any topology that has the same convergent sequences as the uniform topology must be coarser or equal, since its closed sets must be closed under uniform convergence of sequences.

And it is indeed possible to have a strictly coarser topology that still has the same convergent sequences, so the topology is not characterized by this property.

---

##### Counterexample.

For a concrete counter-example, let $X=\mathbb N$, $Y=\mathbb R$.  For every subset  $S\subset \mathbb N$ with asymptotic density $0$, every $\varepsilon>0$, and each $f\in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, define the set
$$U_{\varepsilon,S}(f)=\{g\in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}\mid |g(s)-f(s)|<\varepsilon\,\forall s\in S\}.$$

It is easy to verify these sets, taken over all $\varepsilon>0$, $f\in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, and  $S\subset \mathbb N$ with density $0$, form the base for a topology $\tau$.  Certainly if $f_n\to f$ uniformly, then $f_n\to f$ under $\tau$, since every $\tau$- neighborhood of $f$ includes a uniform neighborhood of $f$.

On the other hand, if $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ uniformly, then there is (after passing to a subsequence if necessary) some $\varepsilon>0$ and some sequence  $(s_n)$ with $|f_n(s_n)-f(s_n)|>\varepsilon$ for each $n$.  After passing to another subsequence if necessary, we may assume that $S:=\{s_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ has asymptotic density $0$, and then each $f_n$ lies outside of $U_{\varepsilon,S}(f)$, so $f_n$ does not converge under $\tau$.

Therefore $\tau$ has the same convergent sequences as the uniform metric.

On the other hand, the $\rho$-ball of radius $r$ around $f$ is not a neighborhood of $f$ in $\tau$, since it does not contain any set $U_{\varepsilon,S}(f)$, so $\tau$ is not the same topology.